# Is it possible in PyCharm to get code completion for Django AND AngularJS template tags?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, pycharm

I have Django / AngularJS project in PyCharm. As far as I can see, I can only enable Django template tags or AngularJS template tags. I understand that it's maybe complicated to have a such a feature that tags are automatically recognized as Django / AngularJS (but it's also sounds possible to me because of Django `verbatim` tag). But, I'm wondering is it possible to, let's say, define which folders in project are under what tag-control, or something like that? So in that case I could have strongly separated files with AngularJS tags as well as files with Django template files.